# URI is not registered in android studio at manifest

Tags: android, uri

I am having URI not resolved in the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

Why?

Comment: paste whole error and xml

Comment: Need whole file I reckon.

Comment: possibly You have Your layout file in the wrong folder....